# Как получить IP адрес клиента? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ip

Пробовал `request()->ip` , возвращает 127.0.0.1

Comment: У Вас php код находится за nginx или какой то другой реверс-проксей?

Comment: А где пробовали то? На локалке у себя?

Comment: @DaemonHK да, на локалке

Comment: :) на локалке оно конечно будет 127.0.0.1. какой ещё ему там быть

Comment: @KoVadim т.е. пока я домен не зарегистрирую - у меня не будет возможности это проверить

Comment: @GrizzlyK Домен Вам не обязателен. Но сайт обязательно должен быть размещён удаленно (хостинг или вдс/дедик).

Answer (score 0):

$this->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR');
$request->getClientIp();